# Select Rows Where Entries are duplicated on a Specific Column

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table where a specific value may be duplicated if another field exists within another group. I'm attempting to figure out how to ignore the entries duplicated.

Consider this table:

```
+--------+-----+----------+
| Amount | CID | GROUP_ID |
+--------+-----+----------+
| 10.0   |   1 | g1       |
| 10.0   |   2 | g1       |
| 5.0    |   1 | g2       |
| 5.0    |   1 | g2       |
+--------+-----+----------+
```

I'd like to return the summed amount, but only use distinct amounts with respect to CID within a group id.

```
+------------+----------+
| net_amount | GROUP_ID |
+------------+----------+
| 10.0       | g1       |
| 10.0       | g2       |
+------------+----------+
```

I've tried grouping by amount and group id and joining on group id, but to no avail.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct sum(amount) as net_amount,group_id from your_table group by group_id,cid;
```

This can help you. Take the distinct of the output, but group it with all the columns you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!